# Qt Creator doesn't build a minimal project [-c line 0: git]

Tags: c++, git, qt, compiler-errors, qt-creator

I've checked the internet but couldn't find anything useful.

I just installed the most rescent Qt from their homepage. Then I started Creator and created a "qt console application". I left everything standard during the project setup and then I hit build and I get the following error message, where I'm totaly lost, since it doesn't make any sence to me:

**Program code**

```
#include <QCoreApplication>
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);

    return a.exec();
}
```

**Build-Problems**

```
"\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin\sh.exe":-1: Error: -c: line 0: syntax error near unexpected token `('
```

and

```
"\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin\sh.exe":-1: Error: -c: line 0: `/Program Files (x86)/Git/bin/sh.exe -c g++ -c -pipe -fno-keep-inline-dllexport -g -frtti -Wall -Wextra -fexceptions -mthreads -DUNICODE -DQT_CORE_LIB -I"..\CyberGloves" -I"." -I"..\..\..\..\Qt\5.4\mingw491_32\include" -I"..\..\..\..\Qt\5.4\mingw491_32\include\QtCore" -I"debug" -I"..\..\..\..\Qt\5.4\mingw491_32\mkspecs\win32-g++"  -o debug\main.o ..\CyberGloves\main.cpp'
```

**Compiler Window**
Here's an excerpt of the compiler window message

```
"/Program Files (x86)/Git/bin/sh.exe": -c: line 0: syntax error near unexpected token `('
"/Program Files (x86)/Git/bin/sh.exe": -c: line 0: `/Program Files (x86)/Git/bin/sh.exe -c g++ -c -pipe -fno-keep-inline-dllexport -g -frtti -Wall -Wextra -fexceptions -mthreads -DUNICODE -DQT_CORE_LIB -I"..\CyberGloves" -I"." -I"..\..\..\..\Qt\5.4\mingw491_32\include" -I"..\..\..\..\Qt\5.4\mingw491_32\include\QtCore" -I"debug" -I"..\..\..\..\Qt\5.4\mingw491_32\mkspecs\win32-g++"  -o debug\main.o ..\CyberGloves\main.cpp'
Makefile.Debug:172: recipe for target 'debug/main.o' failed
mingw32-make[1]: *** [debug/main.o] Error 258
mingw32-make[1]: Leaving directory 'C:/Users/fihle/Documents/build-CyberGloves-Desktop_Qt_5_4_1_MinGW_32bit-Debug'
makefile:34: recipe for target 'debug' failed
mingw32-make: *** [debug] Error 2
11:46:15: Der Prozess "C:\Qt\Tools\mingw491_32\bin\mingw32-make.exe" has been terminated with the return value 2.
```

Well all I see is he's bothering about GIT, when I didn't even touched it (as I said, I took it just right out of the box).

I'm using the QT community version, on a Win7-64 bit machine.

I hope some of you has an idea.

Thanks for your support.

Comment: I think you better use MinGW compiler suite with Qt.

Comment: @PraneethNilangaPeiris can it get any better than the one Qt has setup itself during install?

Comment: You've installed git and you're using its shell. It probably doesn't go along with mingw's binaries due to different newline conventions.

Comment: @molbdnilo what exactly do you mean I'm using its shell, how should Qt even notice about it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

remove c:/Program Files (x86)/Git/bin from %PATH% environment variable, and make sure QT installation and your project directory not locate at any directory with space or any special characters.

Comment: this is working. But don't I have now problems with git, or more probably other programs relying on git?

Comment: You should have a cmd folder inside your git installation folder. Add this to your %path% environment and git can e found by other programs again. Qt Creator will work with this path in your environment.